# Does adding another video card hugely reduce the strain on the first?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, temperature

I've been playing a game which is resource-intensive as it is, but I've since discovered that it causes my video card (which has three monitors connected) to exceed temperatures of 70'C. The framerate when it reaches this temperature is not intolerable but I worry about my card being damaged.

If I added a second video card, thereby reducing the load on the first, plugged only the game monitor into one of them and leaving the other two monitors in the other, that should theoretically allow the first video card to focus entirely on the game without having to support two extra screens of desktop.

What concerns me about this is that one of the video cards will be blowing air at the other one. Is this likely to cause any problem?

Comment: The support of three screens is not particularly demanding when compared to the load during gaming. I doubt that introducing another graphics card will have any effect other than to increase the load on your power supply. Do you play games across all three screens or is the game on one with the desktop or something else shown on the others?

Comment: The game is on one monitor with the desktop (or sometimes browser windows) on the other two.

Comment: video cards vent out the back,when possible 1 empty slot should be allowed between cards, but with the right ventilation they can be packed together.  Additionally, you can get some cards water cooled, and then can be right next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 1 gaming screen and 2 desktops, 2 plain desktops will not significantly burden the GPU.

The real issue is how under powered you current GPU is for this game.  If you have trouble reaching 30fps, and you CROSSFIRE or SLI then both cards will run at max in an effort to give you 60fps.

Most monitors only support 60hz, and if you have vsync ON then the GPU will not make any effort to generate frames higher than that.  Depending on game settings it could also use the additional GPU to increase the quality of the images displayed.

In short, it could lower your primary GPUs load, but it could just max both out in order to increase frames or image quality.  In addition some games don't support CROSSFIRE and/or SLI so there won't be any benefit in those conditions.

If you add a second video card in non CROSSFIRE/SLI at most it will reduce the burden by 10%, and the game will expand and consume that 10%.

Comment: So if I add another video card with Crossfire, even if I don't plug anything into it, the game (assuming Crossfire support) will still use the resources of the extra card. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Some video cards require a special cable, but the newest cards don't even require that.

Answer (score 0):

I would say probably invest in a better cooling system instead, if the quality of the game isn’t bad, and your not getting terrible frame rates then maxing out the video card wouldn’t hurt it any more than normal wear an tear, and cooling it would stop it from over heating like you said it was doing.